# How to make an android app beautiful like this one?

Tags: android, plugins

I'm an amateur android programmer and I really like to code. My main difficulty is to make apps nice.

I came across a simple app, but at the same time, nice: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.linksaude.bulas

I would like to know if this app has been designed with some specific plugin/add-on for Eclipse or whatever. It seems to be so consistent and beautifully designed that there must be an answer to simplify the building process of such apps.

Thanks!

Comment: it's not a programming skill.. it depends on your creativity vision and designing skills. At the example you provided the developer used simple to colors (white - organge) which you must deside before start creating the UI of an app.. pick a colors, use your creativity.. mix them with some simplicity

Answer (score 10):

I think what you're impressed with is the consistent color theme of the application.  It looks like its designers carefully overrode the default design of Android widgets with their own custom scheme.

There is NOT any plugin for development tools that will help you achieve this; however, there are many external tools.

Here is a tool to generate styles for the action bar (the navigation bar at the top):
http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator

A tool to generate custom colored Holo widgets: (Holo is the theme in modern Android platforms):
http://android-holo-colors.com/

And my #1 favorite resource for this type of customization, this website:
http://www.stylingandroid.com/

These three are more than sufficient to customize an interface like the one you linked to above.  Good luck!

Comment: you gave him the tools which is great .. but as @EGHDK said `beauty is in the eye of the beholder`

Answer (score 4):

Though beauty is in the eye of the beholder, this will do the job.

http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

> Welcome to Android Design, your place for learning how to design
>   exceptional Android apps.

Answer (score 0):

There are some DevBytes videos on YouTube of how you make your app beautiful.
The result is an application which looks very modern and beautiful, you should have a look at those [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPyR0nYUXqc)